# Unable to create a HTML button in which when pressed requests a URL, but does not change page

Tags: html

i have been trying to create a html button for my website for my automatic gates. It uses a Arduino program called teleduino, and if you are not familiar with this, you specify what you want the Arduino to do in the URL, so i have the command created for this, but need a button to press. i already have a button which redirects to the teleduino page, but i would prefer it if it could stay on my website. The code i used for the button is:

```
<input type="button" value="Open/Close Gates" style="height:500px;width:500px" onclick="window.location.href='xxxx">
```

it would be preferable if the button was in html.
any help in this would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Something seems to be missing from this question.

Comment: Is it not working because your quotes are all messed up? and there's no beginning bracket? `<input type="button" value="Open/Close Gates" style="height:500px; width:500px" onclick="window.location.href='xxxx'">`

Comment: also as @durbnpoisn, pointed out, we have no idea how you actually collect the information you need.

Comment: That code is working, i just took out the url and accidently removed one of the quotes, and it would not appear in the question

Comment: I edited the post to fix the errors in the initial code.  I also posted an answer to fully explain what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this with straight HTML is to utilize a form with an action.  That, and use an actual SUBMIT element, rather than a button.
The end result, will be the form being submitted to your page, whatever that is.  Whether you choose to do anything with the other form contents is up to you.

```
<form name="formName" id="formName" method="POST" action="page.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Open/Close Gates" style="height:500px;width:500px">
</form>
```